# Binding empty array to chart

Tags: javascript, arrays, highcharts

How do I update a chart to an empty data array to show that there is no data yet, then back to the ones that have data, without the javascript objects being manipulated? I get the error when the data array selected is empty.

I have done a [code sample here](https://jsfiddle.net/rbwafula/1vkebqfd/). Clicking on either 2015, 2016 or 2017 ... no problems! However if I click 2018 which is empty, it affects the other years which should be static data.

To simulate the error:

1. After load, select 2018: Shows no data to display as expected
2. Select 2017: Shows 2017 data, as expected
3. Select 2016: Shows 2016 data, as expected
4. Select 2017: Shows 2016 data, instead of showing 2017 data. JS variable *trafficinfo_data_series_2017* gets updated to 2016 data.

```js
var trafficinfo_data_xaxis_default = [
  ["North America"],["European Union"],
  ["Asia Pacific"],
  ["Australia"],["Africa"]
];
var trafficinfo_data_series_default = [{
  "name": "American Brands",
  "data": [
    [57.37533669],
    [0.117136],
    [0.08759559],
    [0.692],
    [0.35]
  ],
  "stack": "cars"
}, {
  "name": "European Brands",
  "data": [
    [23.92798527],
    [57.37533669],
    [12.541969060000001],
    [14.24307465],
    [11.84693269]
  ],
  "stack": "cars"
}, {
  "name": "Japanese Brands",
  "data": [
    [0.59301429],
    [3],
    [32.95988396],
    [12.158916],
    [0.01123203],
  ],
  "stack": "cars"
}];

$(function() {
  $('#trafficinfo').highcharts({
    colors: ['#cbddad', '#fac58e', '#a0ddea'],
    chart: {
      type: 'bar',
      height: 300,
      style: {
        fontFamily: 'Roboto'
      }
    },
    xAxis: {
      categories: trafficinfo_data_xaxis_default,
      title: {
        text: 0
      }
    },
    yAxis: {
      title: {
        text: 'Amount (USD Millions)',
        align: 'high'
      },
      labels: {
        overflow: 'justify'
      },
      stackLabels: {
        enabled: true,
        formatter: function() {
          return Highcharts.numberFormat((this.total), 2, '.');
        }
      }
    },
    title: {
      text: 'Year 2017'
    },
    tooltip: {
      backgroundColor: {
        linearGradient: [0, 0, 0, 60],
        stops: [
          [0, '#FFFFFF'],
          [1, '#E0E0E0']
        ]
      },
      borderWidth: 1,
      borderColor: '#AAA',
      headerFormat: '<span style="font-size:12px; font-weight:700; text-decoration:underline">{point.key}</span><table>',
      pointFormatter: function() {
        return '<tr><td><i class="fa fa-circle" style="color:' + this.series.color + '"></i> ' + this.series.name + ':</td>' + '<td style="text-align:right; padding:0; font-weight:700;">' + Highcharts.numberFormat((this.y), 2, '.') + ' million</td></tr>';
      },
      footerFormat: '</table>',
      shared: true,
      useHTML: true
    },
    plotOptions: {
      bar: {
        stacking: 'normal'
      },
      series: {
        formatter: function() {
          return Highcharts.numberFormat(this.value, 0);
        },
        dataLabels: {
          enabled: false,
          format: '{point.y:,.2f}',
          style: {
            color: 'black',
            fontWeight: 'normal'
          }
        }
      }
    },
    credits: {
      enabled: false
    },
    series: trafficinfo_data_series_default
  });
});

var trafficinfo_data_xaxis_2015 = [
  ["North America"],
  ["European Union"],
  ["Asia Pacific"],
  ["Australia"],
  ["Africa"]
];
var trafficinfo_data_series_2015 = [{
  "name": "American Brands",
  "data": [
    [41.37533669],
    [0.557136],
    [1.88759559],
    [0.092],
    [3.234]
  ],
  "stack": "cars"
}, {
  "name": "European Brands",
  "data": [
    [18.92798527],
    [37.37533669],
    [10.541969060000001],
    [8.24307465],
    [7.84693269]
  ],
  "stack": "cars"
}, {
  "name": "Japanese Brands",
  "data": [
    [2.59301429],
    [4.74857],
    [18.95988396],
    [6.158916],
    [2.01123203],
  ],
  "stack": "cars"
}];

var trafficinfo_data_xaxis_2016 = [
  ["North America"],
  ["European Union"],
  ["Asia Pacific"],
  ["Australia"],
  ["Africa"]
];
var trafficinfo_data_series_2016 = [{
  "name": "American Brands",
  "data": [
    [47.92798527],
    [1.95988396],
    [1.38759559],
    [0.95492],
    [2.35]
  ],
  "stack": "cars"
}, {
  "name": "European Brands",
  "data": [
    [18.24307465],
    [47.37533669],
    [14.841969060000001],
    [9.64307465],
    [15.84693269]
  ],
  "stack": "cars"
}, {
  "name": "Japanese Brands",
  "data": [
    [2.95988396],
    [4.31048141],
    [35.95988396],
    [14.158916],
    [2.01123203],
  ],
  "stack": "cars"
}];

var trafficinfo_data_xaxis_2017 = [
  ["North America"],
  ["European Union"],
  ["Asia Pacific"],
  ["Australia"],
  ["Africa"]
];
var trafficinfo_data_series_2017 = [{
  "name": "American Brands",
  "data": [
    [57.37533669],
    [0.117136],
    [0.08759559],
    [0.692],
    [0.35]
  ],
  "stack": "cars"
}, {
  "name": "European Brands",
  "data": [
    [23.92798527],
    [57.37533669],
    [12.541969060000001],
    [14.24307465],
    [11.84693269]
  ],
  "stack": "cars"
}, {
  "name": "Japanese Brands",
  "data": [
    [0.59301429],
    [3],
    [32.95988396],
    [12.158916],
    [0.01123203],
  ],
  "stack": "cars"
}];

var trafficinfo_data_xaxis_2018 = [];
var trafficinfo_data_series_2018 = [{
  "name": "American Brands",
  "data": [],
  "stack": "cars"
}, {
  "name": "European Brands",
  "data": [],
  "stack": "cars"
}, {
  "name": "Japanese Brands",
  "data": [],
  "stack": "cars"
}];

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.years input[type=radio]').on('change', function() {
    var selected_year = this.value;

    var chart = $('#trafficinfo').highcharts();
    for (var i = 0; i < eval('trafficinfo_data_series_' + selected_year).length; i++) {
      chart.series[i].setData(eval('trafficinfo_data_series_' + selected_year)[i].data);
    }

    chart.xAxis[0].setCategories(eval('trafficinfo_data_xaxis_' + selected_year));
    chart.setTitle({
      text: "Year " + selected_year
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<html>

<head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/no-data-to-display.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/data.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="btn-group years" data-toggle="buttons">
        <label class="btn btn-primary">
            <input type="radio" name="options" value="2015" autocomplete="off"> 2015
        </label>
        <label class="btn btn-primary">
            <input type="radio" name="options" value="2016" autocomplete="off"> 2016
        </label>
        <label class="btn btn-primary active">
            <input type="radio" name="options" value="2017" autocomplete="off" checked="checked"> 2017
        </label>
        <label class="btn btn-primary">
            <input type="radio" name="options" value="2018" autocomplete="off"> 2018
        </label>
    </div>

    <div id="trafficinfo" style="min-width: 310px; height: 200px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is related to javascript object reference. It was [already reported](https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/5012) and resolved as correct behaviour.. Use `$.expand` if you want to setData multiple times.

Also [avoid using `eval`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/86513/why-is-using-the-javascript-eval-function-a-bad-idea) whenever you can.

```js
$(function() {
  $('#trafficinfo').highcharts({
    colors: ['#cbddad', '#fac58e', '#a0ddea'],
    chart: {
      type: 'bar',
      height: 300,
      style: {
        fontFamily: 'Roboto'
      }
    },
    xAxis: {
      categories: trafficinfo_data.default.xaxis,
      title: {
        text: 0
      }
    },
    yAxis: {
      title: {
        text: 'Amount (USD Millions)',
        align: 'high'
      },
      labels: {
        overflow: 'justify'
      },
      stackLabels: {
        enabled: true,
        formatter: function() {
          return Highcharts.numberFormat((this.total), 2, '.');
        }
      }
    },
    title: {
      text: 'Year 2017'
    },
    tooltip: {
      backgroundColor: {
        linearGradient: [0, 0, 0, 60],
        stops: [
          [0, '#FFFFFF'],
          [1, '#E0E0E0']
        ]
      },
      borderWidth: 1,
      borderColor: '#AAA',
      headerFormat: '<span style="font-size:12px; font-weight:700; text-decoration:underline">{point.key}</span><table>',
      pointFormatter: function() {
        return '<tr><td><i class="fa fa-circle" style="color:' + this.series.color + '"></i> ' + this.series.name + ':</td>' + '<td style="text-align:right; padding:0; font-weight:700;">' + Highcharts.numberFormat((this.y), 2, '.') + ' million</td></tr>';
      },
      footerFormat: '</table>',
      shared: true,
      useHTML: true
    },
    plotOptions: {
      bar: {
        stacking: 'normal'
      },
      series: {
        formatter: function() {
          return Highcharts.numberFormat(this.value, 0);
        },
        dataLabels: {
          enabled: false,
          format: '{point.y:,.2f}',
          style: {
            color: 'black',
            fontWeight: 'normal'
          }
        }
      }
    },
    credits: {
      enabled: false
    },
    series: $.extend(true, [], trafficinfo_data.default.series)
  });
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.years input[type=radio]').on('change', function() {
    var selected_year = this.value;
    
    var chart = $('#trafficinfo').highcharts();
    trafficinfo_data[selected_year].series.forEach(function(serie, index) {
      chart.series[index].setData($.extend(true, [], serie.data));
    });

    chart.xAxis[0].setCategories(trafficinfo_data[selected_year].xaxis);
    chart.setTitle({
      text: "Year " + selected_year
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<html>

<head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/no-data-to-display.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/data.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <script>
      var trafficinfo_data = {
        default: {
          xaxis: [
            ["North America"],["European Union"],
            ["Asia Pacific"],
            ["Australia"],["Africa"]
          ],
          series: [{
            "name": "American Brands",
            "data": [
              [57.37533669],
              [0.117136],
              [0.08759559],
              [0.692],
              [0.35]
            ],
            "stack": "cars"
          }, {
            "name": "European Brands",
            "data": [
              [23.92798527],
              [57.37533669],
              [12.541969060000001],
              [14.24307465],
              [11.84693269]
            ],
            "stack": "cars"
          }, {
            "name": "Japanese Brands",
            "data": [
              [0.59301429],
              [3],
              [32.95988396],
              [12.158916],
              [0.01123203],
            ],
            "stack": "cars"
          }]
        },
        2015: {
          xaxis: [
            ["North America"],
            ["European Union"],
            ["Asia Pacific"],
            ["Australia"],
            ["Africa"]
          ],
          series: [{
            "name": "American Brands",
            "data": [
              [41.37533669],
              [0.557136],
              [1.88759559],
              [0.092],
              [3.234]
            ],
            "stack": "cars"
          }, {
            "name": "European Brands",
            "data": [
              [18.92798527],
              [37.37533669],
              [10.541969060000001],
              [8.24307465],
              [7.84693269]
            ],
            "stack": "cars"
          }, {
            "name": "Japanese Brands",
            "data": [
              [2.59301429],
              [4.74857],
              [18.95988396],
              [6.158916],
              [2.01123203],
            ],
            "stack": "cars"
          }]
        },
        2016: {
          xaxis: [
            ["North America"],
            ["European Union"],
            ["Asia Pacific"],
            ["Australia"],
            ["Africa"]
          ],
          series: [{
            "name": "American Brands",
            "data": [
              [47.92798527],
              [1.95988396],
              [1.38759559],
              [0.95492],
              [2.35]
            ],
            "stack": "cars"
          }, {
            "name": "European Brands",
            "data": [
              [18.24307465],
              [47.37533669],
              [14.841969060000001],
              [9.64307465],
              [15.84693269]
            ],
            "stack": "cars"
          }, {
            "name": "Japanese Brands",
            "data": [
              [2.95988396],
              [4.31048141],
              [35.95988396],
              [14.158916],
              [2.01123203],
            ],
            "stack": "cars"
          }]
        },
        2017: {
          xaxis: [
            ["North America"],
            ["European Union"],
            ["Asia Pacific"],
            ["Australia"],
            ["Africa"]
          ],
          series: [{
            "name": "American Brands",
            "data": [
              [57.37533669],
              [0.117136],
              [0.08759559],
              [0.692],
              [0.35]
            ],
            "stack": "cars"
          }, {
            "name": "European Brands",
            "data": [
              [23.92798527],
              [57.37533669],
              [12.541969060000001],
              [14.24307465],
              [11.84693269]
            ],
            "stack": "cars"
          }, {
            "name": "Japanese Brands",
            "data": [
              [0.59301429],
              [3],
              [32.95988396],
              [12.158916],
              [0.01123203],
            ],
            "stack": "cars"
          }]
        },
        2018: {
          xaxis: [],
          series: [{
            "name": "American Brands",
            "data": [],
            "stack": "cars"
          }, {
            "name": "European Brands",
            "data": [],
            "stack": "cars"
          }, {
            "name": "Japanese Brands",
            "data": [],
            "stack": "cars"
          }]
        },
      }    
    </script>
    <div class="btn-group years" data-toggle="buttons">
        <label class="btn btn-primary">
            <input type="radio" name="options" value="2015" autocomplete="off"> 2015
        </label>
        <label class="btn btn-primary">
            <input type="radio" name="options" value="2016" autocomplete="off"> 2016
        </label>
        <label class="btn btn-primary active">
            <input type="radio" name="options" value="2017" autocomplete="off" checked="checked"> 2017
        </label>
        <label class="btn btn-primary">
            <input type="radio" name="options" value="2018" autocomplete="off"> 2018
        </label>
    </div>

    <div id="trafficinfo" style="min-width: 310px; height: 200px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thanks for that